# Linux - Execute All Bash Scripts in Directory By Date Added

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I am looking for a script that will execute all of the bash scripts in a given directory in the order by which they were added. For example, the earliest scripts added to the directory would be executed first.

This is what I am using now, but it doesn't seem to execute the scripts by date added.

```bsh
for each in /dir/*.sh; 
do 
    bash $each > /dev/null 2>&1 ; 
    rm $each > /dev/null 2>&1 ; 
done ;
```

Let me know how could modify this to order the files in the directory by date added.

Comment: This sounds like a terrible idea. How do you expect order to be easily controlled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean "in order of creation":

```bsh
ls -ctr /dir/*.sh | while read script
do
  bash $script > /dev/null 2>&1
  rm $script > /dev/null 2>&1
done
```

Comment: I can't figure out why it's still interpreting /*.sh as a comment, the language tag is supposed to prevent that.

Comment: Needed blank line before `<!-- language: bash -->`.

Comment: Thank you so much! What I was looking for. I knew it was simple. Thanks, again.

Comment: `-c` is not creation time, it's inode change time. `chmod` will update this timestamp.